# Python, contar los valores (idiomas) que contiene una lista que esta dentro de un diccionario

Tags: python

Buenas tardes y gracias de antemano.

Soy nuevo en programación y estoy realizando los retos de github:
https://github.com/Asabeneh/30-Days-Of-Python/blob/master/10_Day_Loops/10_loops.md#loops

En el reto lo que facilita es una lista con varios diccionarios dentro. Una de las claves que contienen los diccionarios es "languages", y en unos diccionarios el valor es un string y en otros una lista.

Parte del archivo de ejemplo:

```
 "name": "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)",
        "capital": "Sucre",
        "languages": [
            "Spanish",
            "Aymara",
            "Quechua"
        ],
        "population": 10985059,
        "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/bol.svg",
        "currency": "Bolivian boliviano"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba",
        "capital": "Kralendijk",
        "languages": [
            "Dutch"
```

Archivo completo:
https://pastebin.com/6uPUuzMT.

No encuentro la manera de conseguir contar los idiomas que hay en total. He intentado convertir la lista a un set para quitar los repetidos, pero al generar multiples listas....no puedo (no se hacerlo)

Código que intento:

```
lst=[]
for element in countries_data:          # loop para la lista principal
    for k,v in element.items():         # loop para iterar los diccionarios
        if k == "languages" and k not in lst:       # intento filtrar por valor "languages"
            lst.append(v)               # Intento crear una lista con los valores Ok
                
           
for i in lst:       # Bucle para iterar la lista creada
    print(i)
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Rh7iP5UR    Aqui esta el codigo que intento realizar

Comment: Lucato, bienvenido/a al sitio. He editado la pregunta para que el código se vea correctamente. En lo sucesivo puedes hacerlo tú mismo añadiendo una línea con tres ``` delante del código y otra igual detrás.

Comment: Fácil: `unicos = len(set(lang for pais in lista for lang in pais["languages"]))`

Comment: Muchas gracias @Abulafia Acabo de recibir un baño de conocimiento y estoy releyendo varias veces para enterarme bien. Habia "conseguido" realizarlo cambiando del método append() a extend(), pero sin lugar a duda tal y como lo planteas es lo mejor. Visto así es sencillo, haber si el cerebro me genera conexiones nuevas.

Comment: Gracias @CandidMoe

Answer (score 2):

El problema que (supongo) tenías al tratar de usar conjuntos es que usabas un `.add(element["lenguajes"])`, pero ya que `element["lenguajes"]` es una lista, te daba error porque las listas no pueden ser añadidas a un conjunto (los conjuntos sólo pueden contener elementos inmutables).

Pero es que de hecho no querías añadir la lista, sino los contenidos de esa lista (que son los idiomas concretos). Para ello en lugar de `.add()` debes usar `.update()`. Esta función sí que espera una lista como parámetro y añade al conjunto los elementos de esa lista. De modo que un código que sí funciona sería este:

```
lenguajes = set()
for element in countries_data:
  lenguajes.update(element["languages"])
```

Ese bucle deja en `lenguajes` el conjunto de todos los lenguajes diferentes.  Puedes aplicar `len()` sobre el mismo. Salen 112 lenguajes.